# Reusing socket when copying large amounts of data

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently sending large amounts of data over a Java socket, and I am using the [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) library to copy using the `copyLarge` method to send/receive the data. The problem is that the `copyLarge` reads until the the input stream returns -1. I have copied a snippet below

```
while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, n);
   count += n;
}
```

This method will block until the socket is closed, but the problem is I want to reuse the socket to additional large data. The alternatives I see are to either reopen a new socket for each data being transferred, or to write my own read method that looks for an end of stream token (i.e. a newline character).

It has been a while since I've written low level socket code like this, but am I missing something here? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: It's actually not that difficult, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how much data you have before sending it over? If so, I'd basically length-prefix the message.

That's *much* easier to handle cleanly than using an end-of-stream token and having to worry about escaping, over-reading etc.

But yes, you'll need to do *something*, because TCP/IP is a stream-based protocol. Unless you have some indicator for the end of data *somehow*, you never know whether there might be some more to come Real Soon Now.

Comment: thanks. I do know the length of the data. I was hoping to use IOUtils.copyLarge (or something similar) to send it since that implementation such boilerplate code that I feel like I shouldn't need to write it again. Do you know of any libraries that that are similar but allow for specifying the length?

Comment: @Jeff: Not offhand, I'm afraid - but that code should be easy to adapt.

Comment: agreed - easy to adapt, just hoping I didn't have to ... oh well, guess I will. Thanks.